# Import for custom product prices for customer groups?

Tags: bigcommerce

I work for a company that has a concept of pricing rules for our different customers, or in other words different prices for certain customers for certain products. I have found that it is possible to add customer-group product-level fixed cost adjustments, but in order to do that someone would manually have to type in the products and fill in the fixed price values, and that would be very time consuming for thousands of products for all of the different customers.

So I am wondering if there is some way to import fixed price values for products for a specific customer group? Or even if there is a faster way at all than going in and clicking one at a time on all of the different products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your store is on BigCommerce Enterprise, we have an upcoming feature called Price Lists that might be able to help you.

I'd be happy to get you guys into the beta if you're on the appropriate plan.